# MySQL Query takes too long when using left join and order by from joined table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query that works very fast (around 0.2862seconds):

```
SELECT title, godina,
       (SELECT zanrovi.zanr 
        FROM zanrovi
        WHERE filmovi.zanr=zanrovi.id
       ) AS zanr,
       imdb, ocjena, sd, hd, fhd, 3d ,
       (SELECT COUNT(film)
        FROM statistika
        WHERE film=filmovi.id
       ) AS skinuto
FROM filmovi LEFT JOIN
     zanrovi
     ON filmovi.podzanrovi=zanrovi.id
ORDER BY filmovi.id DESC
LIMIT 0, 32
```

So I need this query to `ORDER BY skinuto`

So I modify the above query to do so:

```
SELECT title, godina,
       (SELECT zanrovi.zanr
        FROM zanrovi
        WHERE filmovi.zanr=zanrovi.id
       ) AS zanr,
       imdb, ocjena, sd, hd, fhd, 3d,
       (SELECT COUNT(film)
        FROM statistika
        WHERE film=filmovi.id
       ) AS skinuto
FROM filmovi LEFT JOIN
     zanrovi
     ON filmovi.podzanrovi=zanrovi.id
ORDER BY skinuto DESC
LIMIT 0, 32
```

And the query is executed in 41.328seconds!? So this is too long...so I see that if I user skinuto from another table that there is a delay so the question is how can I order by skinuto so that query will execute fast as it should be?

When I remove ORDER BY skinuto and replace with ORDER BY filmovi.id then it executes very fast (below 0,5seconds) and I need to order by skinuto. I am missing something in the code?

Thanks.

Comment: the use of subselect and join  is not clear  please  .. update  your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result ..

Comment: Have you used `EXPLAIN` to see what parts are taking longest, what indexes are available, etc, etc?  If not, please run it and add the findings to your question.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html  Also, perhaps the table definitions for the tables you're using, so that we can see what indexes you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should always use fully qualified column names in queries that reference more than one table.   Your subqueries should look like:

```
. . .
       (SELECT COUNT(s.film)
        FROM statistika s
        WHERE s.film = f.id
       ) AS skinuto
FROM filmovi f LEFT JOIN
     zanrovi z
     ON f.podzanrovi = z.id
```

This makes the query much easier to understand.

You may have no way to improve performance.  But the place to start is with the following indexes:

- `zanrovi(id, zanr)`
- `statistika(film)`

This will speed the subqueries.

I also wonder if the outer join to `zanrovi` is needed.  You are using it in a subquery, so that is suspicious.

If that doesn't do much, consider more filtering in the `FROM` clause.  It also seems like the subquery for `zanr` is unnecessary due to the `JOIN` in the outer query:

```
SELECT title, godina, z.zanr,
       imdb, ocjena, sd, hd, fhd, 3d ,
       s.skinuto
FROM (SELECT s.film, COUNT(s.film) as skinuto
      FROM statistika s
      GROUP BY s.film
      ORDER BY skinuto DESC
      LIMIT 0, 32
     ) s LEFT JOIN
     filmovi f
     ON s.film = f.id LEFT JOIN
     zanrovi z
     ON f.podzanrovi = z.id
ORDER BY s.skinuto DESC;
```

This assumes that all films in `statistika` are in `filmovi`.

Comment: It works like it should be very fast using your code..thanks